Woocommerce Run Once For All Users: wc_update_new_customer_past_orders
I'd like to run a PHP snippet from time to time to link Woocommerce Guest orders to Wordpress Users with the same email. I'm attempting to run the function wc_update_new_customer_past_orders for all users.
I've put the code below in a PHP snippet set to execute once and this hasn't worked.
$users = get_users();
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user->ID );
    }

Can anyone tell me how to run the function "wc_update_new_customer_past_orders" for all wordpress users please ?

What is $users give the full code.

sorry the first line of code wasnt displayed, I've corrected this.

I've tried a few things and I think this is harder to do than I thought.  Maybe at some point a kind person will give a solution.

I've found this works well.
Added it in a code snippet plugin, I turn it on every now and again and use the wp-control plugin to run wp_site_health_scheduled_check.
//hooking into some default wp/wc event like, this one runs weekly
add_action( 'wp_site_health_scheduled_check', 'check_past_orders_registered1' );
hooked to this function

//cron function
function check_past_orders_registered1() {
    $users = get_users();
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user->ID );
    }
}

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/29138#issuecomment-1030234004
Ive tried the same code in a snippet set to run once and that doesnt work for me.
$users = get_users();
        foreach ( $users as $user ) {
            wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user->ID );
        }

